# Haskell - Implementing Monoid what happens if the operator is not associative

Tags: haskell, monoids

According to the definition or a monoid the binary operator must be associative e.g. `A op (B op C) == (A op B) op C`.

The [base `mconcat` definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-Monoid.html) in haskell is:

```
mconcat = foldr mappend mempty
```

Since I know the implementation details of the `mconcat` function, would anything bad happen from defining and using fake monoids where the function isn't associative? Like for example defining instances for subtraction or division.

Could this be useful or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing bad would happen in terms of type safety: Your programs will still not crash.

But a data structure relying on your `Monoid` instance might give unexpected or wrong results.

Consider a tree that is re-balanced upon insertion, and that provides a way to combine its elements using their `Monoid` instance. Then the re-balancing, which is supposed to be an internal operation and not visible to you becomes observable, and referential transparency is “morally broken” – same input (up to supposedly hidden internals), but different output.

Comment: I'd argue that's worse than crashing.  But I guess there's no way around it if someone wishes to insist that `a-(b-c) == (a-b)-c` should hold...